# Finding Area Under a Curve

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I'm attempting to determine the area under a curve $ y = \sin x $ with $ 0 < x < \pi $ and I'm struggling to do so. I managed to graph the function and fill the plot but I cannot figure out how to find the area.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integrate[Sin[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}]
```